# Should I nest immutable.js Map and List in redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am using immutable.js in a redux application and I am wondering whether I should always use immutable.js datastructures where I would have used JSON object or array in a normal application.

Otherwise said, should the store of a redux application be a **pure** immutable.js datastructure or it's okay to mix with plain old javascript objects and arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It's totally okay to use "old" javascript objects or array. If you use immutable.js everywhere, you will get more advantages than using "old" js objects. From [their website](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), immutable.js is `leading to much simpler application development, no defensive copying, and enabling advanced memoization and change detection techniques with simple logic.`. It will enforce the use of functional programming patterns like pure function, which redux use a lot. You will avoid useless object mutation and related bugs. Your code will be more along the lines of the redux way of thinking. It might take more time to code with immutable.js, but your code will be better, faster and easier to update overall. Since you're using react. You won't get a lot of benefits using immutable.js inside a component because react has a great way to handle object change easily. I will suggest you to try to keep your redux store as pure immutable.js data structure as possible to avoid strange side effects and bugs. You will become used to it, but like I said before, it's totally fine to use non immutable-js data structure. Sometimes it will be easier not to use it. I will suggest you to try using it everywhere and you will be able to see by yourself if it's a waste of time or not.